# List all Azure AD groups ending with "reader"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Im trying to list all azure ad groups where the displayname ends with "Reader"

```
Get-AzureRmADGroup -SearchString "Reader"
```

And the Microsoft example says

```
Example 2: Get groups by search string
This command gets all Active Directory groups that **include** Patti in the display name.


Windows PowerShell
PS C:\> Get-AzureRmADGroup -SearchString "Patti"
```

But my result is blank when i try to do this, what I'm i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below.

```
Get-AzureRmADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*Reader"}
```

**Test Result**(In order to speed up the operation, use a `-First 5`, you can ignore it):

[image]

Comment: Perfect you are like a god or something! :)